# Strange 3D output from rasterVis::plot3D when plotting a digital elevation model

Tags: r, 3d, visualization, raster, rastervis

I'm trying to plot a few 3D digital elevation models using `rasterVis::plot3D`.

The DEMs are originally geo tifs, they are all DEMs of the same location just different areas in that location and they all have the same coordinate reference system ("+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), the only thing that differs is the spatial extent and resolution. One is an area of approx. 200 x 700 meters at 2 meter resolution and the rest are 1 x 1m at 1cm resolution. The x and y values are coordinates and z is elevation. They all plot just fine and look normal when plotting them in 2D.

However, when I plot the larger area 2m resolution DEM using `rasterVis::plot3D` I get a beautiful 3D plot:

[image: 2m resolution 3D DEM]

just as expected, but when I plot any of the smaller, finer resolution DEMs I get a very strange output

[image: strange 1cm resolution 3D DEM].

I can't figure out what is causing this strange output.

[Onedrive link to download the geo tif file](https://uowmailedu-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/krandall_uow_edu_au/EXhjMVstzVFAtG-Oz6LpppkBt69BA8Ax-gfmAjUFCGSGMQ?e=CDAbTd)

This is what `Q1cm.tif` looks like when plotted in 2D (the square is a plastic quadrat - we did a vegetation survey within the quadrat).

[image: 2D DEM of Q1cm.tif]

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(rgl)

dem2m<-raster("lidar.tif")
dem1cm<-raster("Q1cm.tif")

dem2m
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 197, 292, 57524  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2, 2  (x, y)
extent     : 360047, 360631, 3080519, 3080913  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : lidar.tif 
names      : lidar 
values     : 18.7875, 59.18345  (min, max)

dem1cm
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 314, 336, 105504  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent     : 360091.7, 360095, 3080597, 3080601  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : Q1cm 
values     : 54.84027, 55.15403  (min, max)

rgl::open3d()
plot3D(dem1cm)
```

Any ideas on what's going on or how to get around the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second image looks like much smaller resolution than 314x336.  After you plot it, you can find out the resolution using `rgl.attrib(ids3d()$id, "dim")`.  To me it looks like it's about 60x20.  Are you possibly clipping it?

Comment: @user2554330 thanks for the response :) I haven't clipped it, but it does have different dimensions to the original raster image, although still high resolution. 

``
> plot3D(dem1cm)
> rgl.attrib(ids3d()$id, "dim")
       r   c
[1,] 327 305
``

Comment: @user2554330 I've just added a link to my question where you can download the Q1cm tif if you'd like to see if you get the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is rounding errors.  Most `rgl` graphics uses single precision floating point, and that's not enough for your data.  For example, the y values range from 10716468 to 10716479.  In single precision there appear to be just 12 distinguishable values in that range (i.e. the whole numbers).  That's why your plot looks so weird:  whole ranges of y values are overplotted at the same location because of the rounding to single precision.

Your actual data is stored in double precision, which is fine.  I think you could get a plot if you subtracted the mean of the x and y values (or the min, or max:  basically anything in that range) from the ones extracted from your dataset.  The subtraction needs to happen before you send the data to `rgl`, and then when `rgl` rounds it to single precision, you won't lose so much.

Unfortunately I don't know enough about `raster` and `rasterVis` to know how to do that.  The `raster::scale()` function appears to do that for the z values, but they're not the problem here.

EDITED to add:  @BenBolker provided the solution.  You can modify the "extent" of the raster using the `extent<-` function.  For example,

```
E <- as.vector(extent(dem1cm))
extent(dem1cm) <- E - rep(E[c(1, 3)], each = 2)
plot3D(dem1cm)
decorate3d()    # adds the scale
```

which produces a plot that looks like this (after some rotation):

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Nice! By brute force: `E <- extent(dem1cm); extent(dem1cm) <- c(E@xmin-360000, E@xmax-360000, E@ymin-3080000, E@ymax-3080000); plot3D(dem1cm)`

Comment: better: `E <- as.vector(extent(demi1cm)); extent(dem1cm) <- E-rep(c(360000, 3080000), each = 2)`

Comment: oh my gosh, I have to say I'm pretty mind blown by that, and very appreciative! Thank you both so much!